# MySQL Actibity without any active visitors via Google Analytics

Tags: mysql

I am hosting a WP website on a VPS (Debian) and I noticed that my MySQL service is constantly being processed, even without any active live visitors that I can see on Google Analytics.

I am aware that there are crawlers from search engines that try to get the content.

Is there a valid way to prevent overloading my MySQL service by ghost visitors (force visitors to be processed via the Google Analytics? Enable Java?)? Or prevent unwanted bots and crawlers?

Comment: I don't really understand your question .. It reads like your website was poorly programmed and so a few visitors already overload the database. Every properly cached WordPress site should have no problem with having "ghost visitors" and bots pinging the site

Comment: What is a "properly cached site"?

Comment: I installed a caching plugin, and still get bombarded by many queries.